# Block-Based NSNotificationCenter Observing With Subclasses?

Tags: ios, objective-c, subclass, objective-c-blocks, nsnotificationcenter

I have a class `Poster` which posts notifications through the `NSNotificationCenter`. I have two different observers: `ObserverSuperclass` and `ObserverSubclass`. `ObserverSuperclass` is the superclass of `ObserverSubclass`. I'd like each class to respond differently to the notification.

According to [NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/nsnotification-and-nsnotificationcenter/), I should use the modern block-based api: `addObserverForName:object:queue:usingBlock:`.

In `ObserverSubclass`'s initialization method, I need to remove the superclass as an observer. Because I'm using the block-based API, I need to reference the return value of `addObserverForName:object:queue:usingBlock:` - an "opaque object to act as the observer". So I write the following code:

In `ObserverSuperclass.h`

`@property (nonatomic, strong) id observer;`

In `ObserverSuperclass.m`

`self.observer = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:@"Help!" object:nil queue:nil usingBlock:^{old block}];`

In `ObserverSubclass.m`

`[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self.observer name:@"Help!" object:nil];`

`self.observer = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:@"Help!" object:nil queue:nil usingBlock:^{new block}];`

Is this actually the best way to do this? I'm not sure it makes sense to use the block-based API here.

Comment: You could implement a method that returns the handler block.  Then you can simply override this method in the subclass, or just use the selector based API

Comment: Why do you need to remove the superclass as an observer? Don't you want that block to execute at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a case where, in my opinion, you should use the traditional @selector callbacks instead. Your superclass can register the observation and implement the default behavior. The subclass then needs only override the called back @selector.

The method that you should implement is:

```
- (void)addObserver:(id)notificationObserver
       selector:(SEL)notificationSelector
           name:(NSString *)notificationName
         object:(id)notificationSender
```

For example, in the superclass:

```
- (instancetype) init
{   ...
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
            addObserver:self 
               selector:@selector(oberserveThis:)
                   name:@"someEventName"
                 object:nil];
}

- (void)observeThis:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    // ... Do something here ...
}
```

In your subclass:

```
- (void)observeThis:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    // ... Do something else here ...
}
```

If you need the code in the observer to execute on a specific queue you can always call dispatch within the observation selector. I think that, for your use case, it makes for much cleaner code than using the block based approach.

Comment: This is the conclusion that I came to as well. I'd only use the block-based API if I knew I wouldn't be subclassing.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine.

The logic you've mapped out enforced the idea that you only want one observer, either the superclass or the subclass. Your subclass' observer removes and replaces the superclass' observer.

It's also valid to have them both observing the same notification name. In that case you'd add a new instance variable self.newObserver to the subclass and add an observer to that property as well. Then both blocks would get invoked when a "Help!" notification is posted.

Which you do depends on what you're trying to accomplish.

You DO need to remove an observer when you don't need it any more, or you risk crashing when the objects the observer block deals with get deallocated out from under it. (This is less likely with block-based observers than with selector-based observers, because the notification center retains the block automatically, and even if the object that adds the observer gets deallocated the observer block will still run. With a selector based observer you MUST remember to remove your observer in your dealloc method or you crash after your object is deallocated if the type of notification you are observing gets posted again.)

Comment: This system becomes a little clunky when there the height of the parent-child tree is greater than 2. e.g. the 3rd class (which is a subclass of 1 and 2) would have self.observer, self.newObserver, self.newNewObserver. Instead of storing them as individual properties, use an array?

Comment: This gets especially dirty when the listening classes have multiple observers. Should I then have multiple arrays (or sets of self.observer[N])?

Comment: Sure, an array would be fine. Make the base class have a mutable array of observer objects that it creates at init time. Each subclass that needs it's own observer would create a new observer and add it to the array. The base class's dealloc method could take care of removing all of them.

Comment: This sound like a lot of complexity however. Do you really need a base class and it's child classes to have separate observers for the same event? Another way to handle it would be to have the observer call a method that is defined in the base class. Then have each subclass implement a version of that method that also calls super.